# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: undefined

I have error on Wordpress. Help please )

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/userpro/public_html/wp-content/themes/hoon/inc/tweaks.php on line 602

Comment: Also this on the same line PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/userpro/public_html/wp-content/themes/hoon/inc/tweaks.php on line 602

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: /** * Display Future Posts * * Display future post in the events category to all users. */ function hoon_show_all_future_posts( $posts ) {

global $wp_query, $wpdb;

if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
    $events_cat = hoon_option( 'events_category' );
    $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
        // below line 602 //
    if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID )  || in_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID ) ) {
        $posts = $request;
    }
}

return $posts;
} add_filter( 'the_posts', 'hoon_show_all_future_posts' );

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * Display Future Posts
 *
 * Display future post in the events category to all users.
 */
function hoon_show_all_future_posts( $posts ) {

```
global $wp_query, $wpdb;

if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
    $events_cat = hoon_option( 'events_category' );
    $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
        // below line 602 //
    if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID )  || in_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID ) ) {
        $posts = $request;
    }
}

return $posts;
```

}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'hoon_show_all_future_posts' );